# is there a way to allign a form button to a cell and assign another sub to it

Tags: vba, excel

Question has been solved how to make multiple buttons reference different adjacent offset cells

Sub Tester()
    Dim btn As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

```
lastRow = 99999 'Modify as needed this will be the last possible row to add a button

For i = 2 To lastRow Step 4
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 21)  'Column 2, row i

    '## Create the button object and assign a variable to represent it
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 1, 1)

    '## use the btn variable to manipulate the button:
    With btn
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .width = rng.width
        .height = rng.RowHeight
        .OnAction = "offsetRelative"
        .Caption = "Close"
    End With
Next
End Sub

Sub offsetrelative()
Dim rowNumber As Long
'## Get the row number of the button:
rowNumber = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheets("Sheet6").Range("AD" & CStr(rowNumber)).Value = 1

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**the above solution works great but is a little slow to calculate whenever I click a button. I need it to be instant but it hangs for 5 seconds...is there any way to avoid this?**

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already know that `Buttons.Add()` returns the new button and can be stored in a variable and used wherever it's getting `Shapes("Button 24")`, but I thought I should mention it for completeness.

For doing a different action from each button, you can assign them all the same subroutine, and write a single subroutine that uses `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell` to determine the cell that the button is in, and decides what to do based on the address of the cell.

You can address cells relatively from the known cell with the `.Offset(x, y)` property or e.g. `.Row` instead of using `Sheet.Range`, to avoid having to dynamically calculate ranges, if every section the buttons are in is laid out the same way.

```
Sub offsetrelative()
    Dim myCell as Range
    Dim myRow as Long 
    myCell = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell 
    myRow = myCell.Row - 2 ' D9 = 7
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("AE" & CStr(row)).Value = 1
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("AE" & CStr(row)).Value = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Another thing you could try is encoding the row number in the button name. So you can set `.Name = "Button_Row" & CStr(i)` when you create the button, and then don't use `myCell` at all and use `myRow = CLng(Mid(Application.Caller, 11))` in the offsetrelative function. The 11 is the first character position of the number, it depends on the length of your prefix which was "Button_Row" [10 characters long] in this example.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73853/discussion-on-answer-by-random832-is-there-a-way-to-allign-a-form-button-to-a-ce).

Comment: thanks random I will try that - can it be 11 even for button number 2000 ?

Comment: Yes this is why I used Mid - the parameter is the start of the number from the left.

Comment: do I ommit `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AD" & CStr(i)).Value = 1` ? I seriously hate this problem - didnt want to have to say it

Comment: I don't know what that line is or which function it is in, I've never seen it before. There's no `i` variable in the offsetrelative function, and you're not setting any values in the Tester function, in the versions I have seen. You keep changing your code around.

Comment: im referencing AD not AE - I put dim mycell as range, dim my row as long . myrow = clng..... then what?

Comment: ...then the rest of the offsetrelative function is unchanged. You don't need mycell at all. How does this answer the issue that you asked me if you should omit a line that you have never shown me and I know nothing about. Also please continue this in the chat instead of here.

Comment: @Jonwhite What part don't you get?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  I'm going to use the first line from your recorded macro, and integrate with the `Tester` attempt you have made.  Then put it in a loop to create as many buttons as you want.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim btn as Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i as Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = 100 'Modify as needed this will be the last possible row to add a button

    For i = 3 to lastRow Step 4 
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)  'Column 2, row i

        '## Create the button object and assign a variable to represent it
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 1, 1)

        '## use the btn variable to manipulate the button:
        With btn
            .Top = rng.Top
            .Left = rng.Left
            .Width = rng.Width
            .Height = rng.RowHeight
            .onAction = "offsetRelative"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I modify your `offsetRelative` function to use the `Application.Caller` to determine the cell/range where the button resides, and get the row number from that. Then, instead of hard-coding in the range like "AE3", we can combine the column "AE" with the row number:

```
Sub offsetrelative()
Dim rowNumber as Long
'## Get the row number of the button:
rowNumber = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Sheets("sheet2").Range("AE" & Cstr(rowNumber)).Value = 1
     Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
     Sheets("sheet2").Range("AE" & Cstr(rowNumber)).Value = 0
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73854/discussion-on-answer-by-david-zemens-is-there-a-way-to-allign-a-form-button-to-a).